# How to transform timestamp field with a specific timezone when using Kafka Connect?

Tags: time, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, timestamp-with-timezone

I am using the Kafka Connect with MySQL database to get data.

I need transform a specific column with one determined timezone.

I try this, but I get timezone with UTC.

```
transforms=convert_op_ts
transforms.convert_op_ts.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.convert_op_ts.field=hour_field
transforms.convert_op_ts.format=HH:mmz
transforms.convert_op_ts.target.type=string
```

I search how define format in: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone

I would like to set something like this `transforms.convert_op_ts.format=HH:mm+03` to specify the timezone, it is possible?

Comment: What data is in the database exactly? What Kafka records do you expect? Why not change your JDBC query to use some conversion to seconds, or just minutes past UTC of that day? IMO, hours and minutes alone shouldn't have a "timezone" since the date is also important because, over history, timezones have changed

Comment: I make streaming of many tables from MySQL, so I do not change the query because I use the property `schema.whitelist` to get data of all tables from schema. I have fields with date and others with hour:minutes only.

Comment: If the fields are only `HH:mm`, then they don't have a timezone, so what are you trying to convert? Also, why separate columns when you can use Mysql Date functions to extract that from timestamp fields?